Firebase's getRedirectResult() always returns null even after successfully logging in via signInWithRedirect()
When calling:
await signInWithRedirect(auth, googleProvider);

The browser redirects to the Google Sign In page, where the user signs in, and then redirects back to my website. At this point, calling getRedirectResult() via useEffect should return the authenticated user, but it doesn't. Instead, it always returns null. How can I fix that?
useEffect(() => {
    async function handleRedirectResult() {
      try {
        // result is always null even after successfully logging in
        const result = await getRedirectResult(auth); 
        if (result) {
          const user = result.user;
          console.log('User info:', user);
          updateCurrentUser(user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during redirect sign-in:', error);
      }
    };

    handleRedirectResult();
  }, []);

I also tried using .then and .catch, but to no avail.
useEffect(() => {
  getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then((result) => {
      // result is always null even after successfully logging in
      if (result) {
        const user = result.user;
        console.log('User info:', user);
        updateCurrentUser(user);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during redirect sign-in:', error);
    });
}, []);

P.S. There were no errors thrown
